# ShellJs execute CLI command

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, codeceptjs

I'm using `codeceptjs` with `shelljs`.

In one of tests I'm invoking `go` application like this :

```
const shell = require('shelljs')


shell.exec('./myGoApplication')
```

When application is started and correctly working I have a CLI that is listening for input from console via keyboard so I can type text and my application is getting it.

But when I execute this command seems its not transferring to the input and application is not invoking commands.

`shell.exec('my text')`

Does someone know how to make shellJs make command to my CLI waiting for console input?

go cli:

```
func StartCLI(relay RelayConn) {
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("[?] To see avaliable commands write /?")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        for {
            text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
            text = strings.Trim(text, "\n")

            switch true {
            case strings.HasPrefix(text, "/?"):
                fmt.Println(helpText)
    
            default:
                relay.Chat("Default Member Simulation chat message")
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of writing this answer, it is not possible for processes launched via `exec` to accept input. See [issue #424](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/issues/424) for details.

From the [ShellJS FAQ](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/wiki/FAQ#running-interactive-programs-with-exec):

> We don't currently support running commands in exec which require interactive input. The correct workaround is to use the native `child_process` module:
>
> ```js
> child_process.execFileSync(commandName, [arg1, arg2, ...], {stdio: 'inherit'});
> ```
>
> Using `npm init` as an example:
>
> ```js
> child_process.execFileSync('npm', ['init'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
> ```

Your code should therefore be something like this:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process')

child_process.execFileSync('./myGoApplication', {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

Setting the [`stdio` option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) to `'inherit'` means that stdin, stdout, and stderr of the child process is sent to the parent processes' (`process.stdin`, `process.stdout`, and `process.stderr`), so you should be able to type in input to your Node.js program to send it to your Go program.

See the [documentation on `child_process.execFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options) for more deatils.